# Simplemodal jquery problem

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I was using simple module jquery plugins, its great but I have one small issues regarding this.

I want to close the current module window and open same  after executing some ajax, but it does close and open.

I used the following code.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
       {
       jQuery('a.delete').click(function(){
       id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
       $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '<?=base_url()?>cart/delete/'+id+ '/',
              cache: false,
              success: function(data) {
              alert(id);
                  // jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('<?php echo site_url('cart');?>').modal();
              $.modal.impl.close();
                 }
              });


       return false;
       });
});
</script>
```

The $.modal.impl.close(); command does not work anymore

Could you please help me regarding this?
Thanks
Umesh

Comment: The code you provided does not seem complete, but $.modal.close(); will close any open dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

I looked over the website of the plugin, and didn't see any mention of $.modal.impl.close();  but only of $.modal.close();  So maybe this function is outdated and not included in the latest version.

What is the difference between the two? I guess modal.close() should work anyway.

I didn't understand what you are exactly trying to perform : you don't want to really close the dialog box but just hide it and then show it again after some treatment? If I misunderstood, could you be more explicit please?

Have a nice day ;)